# div in front of flowplayer of external website

Tags: javascript, html, css, z-index, flowplayer

I embedded an external site that has an flowplayer object. For highlighting a specific time mark, I use an overlay div.

Unfortunately, flowplayer hides the div. Is there any workaround to place the div above a flowplayer object if you can't change the parameters of flowplayer?

Comment: have you tried setting z-index for the div to a higher value ?

Comment: yes I did. flowplayer hides it when loaded, no matter which value I choose